# In Axios, how do I capture the response error body that the network tab reports?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios

I’m using axios 0.21.1.  When I make a POST request, I get a 400 error, and I can see this response in my dev tools -> network tab's "Response" tab,

```
{"data":[" value does not allow numbers"]}
```

How do I capture that error in a variable?  I tried this

```
  axios.post(`/api/myendpoint`,
    { 
      data: 2
    },
    {
      headers: {'ACCEPT': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(response => {
      …
    })
    .catch(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
```

But “response.data” prints out “undefined”.  I’ve also tried “response.body” but also undefined.

Comment: If I get an error while making a request, I suggest you test the requests in "postman" first.  Content-length, Content-type may be an error because of such values.If you are catching an error, the request operation is unsuccessful. Therefore, the response object is not created. I suggest you to use Postman for error detection.

Comment: My question is not how do I prevent an error -- my question is given that an error occurs, how do I get the body of waht the error says in Axios?  The body of the error is visible in devtools (and Postman) and I wish to capture that programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the error, check the status and use it however you want

```
 axios.post(`/api/myendpoint`,
{ 
  data: 2
},
{
  headers: {'ACCEPT': 'application/json'}
},
.then(response => {
  …
})
.catch((error) => {
   if (error.response && error.response.status === 400)  {
      let errorVar = error.response.data;
      console.log(errorVar);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should catch the error and return the body like this:

```
.catch(error) => {
  console.log(error.response.data);
}
```

Details in the [Axios document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors)